# How to convert SVG polylines to quickdraw stroke-3 numpy format?

Tags: python, numpy, svg

I would like to convert a basic SVG file containing polylines into the stroke-3 format used by [sketch-rnn](https://github.com/magenta/magenta/tree/master/magenta/models/sketch_rnn#creating-your-own-dataset) (and the [quickdraw dataset](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/quickdraw-dataset#sketch-rnn-quickdraw-dataset)).

To my understanding, each polyline point in stroke-3 format would be:

- stored as `[delta_x, delta_y, pen_up]`, where
- `delta_x`, `delta_y` represent the coordinates relative to the
  previous point and
- `pen_up` is a bit that is 1 when the pen is up
  (e.g. `move_to` operation a-la turtle graphics) or 0 when the pen is
  down (e.g. `line_to` operation a-la turtle graphics).

I've attempted to write the function and convert an SVG, but I when I render a test of the stroke-3 format I get an extra line.

My input SVG looks like this:

[image: box svg]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><svg viewBox="0 0 900 900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="none" stroke="#00c000" stroke-linecap="round"><path d="m324.56 326.77h62.721 62.721 62.721 62.721"/><path d="m575.44 326.77 0.1772 62.891 0.1771 62.891 0.1772 62.891 0.1771 62.891"/><path d="m576.15 578.33h-63.075-63.075l-63.075-1e-4h-63.075"/><path d="m323.85 578.33 0.1772-62.891 0.1772-62.891 0.1772-62.891 0.1771-62.891"/><path d="m575.44 326.77 29.765-32.469 29.765-32.469" stroke="#c00000"/><path d="m634.97 261.83h-92.486-92.486l-92.486-1e-4h-92.486" stroke="#c00000"/><path d="m265.03 261.83 44.647 48.704 14.882 16.235" stroke="#c00000"/><path d="m323.85 578.33-15.092 13.725-30.183 27.45-15.092 13.725" stroke="#c0c000"/><path d="m263.48 633.23h93.258 93.258l93.258 1e-4h93.258" stroke="#c0c000"/><path d="m636.52 633.23-60.366-54.9" stroke="#c0c000"/><path d="m634.97 261.83 0.3863 92.851 0.3862 92.851 0.3863 92.851 0.3863 92.851" stroke="#0000c0"/><path d="m636.52 633.23h-93.258l-93.258-1e-4h-93.258-93.258" stroke="#0000c0"/><path d="m263.48 633.23 0.3863-92.851 0.3863-92.851 0.3863-92.851 0.3862-92.851" stroke="#0000c0"/></g></svg>
```

Here is a visualisation where the lines parsed from the SVG file are rendered in thick green and the lines drawn from the converted stroke-3 format are rendered in thinner red:
[image: box line and strokes]

Notice the diagonal line on the right hand side face which isn't present in the original SVG.

I must be doing something wrong marking a line operation instead of a move operation somewhere, but I've been staring at the code for so long I can't spot the error.

This is a minimal example showing my attempt using svg.path:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import numpy as np
from svg.path import parse_path
from svg.path.path import Line, Move

cubeSVG = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><svg viewBox="0 0 900 900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="none" stroke="#00c000" stroke-linecap="round"><path d="m324.56 326.77h62.721 62.721 62.721 62.721"/><path d="m575.44 326.77 0.1772 62.891 0.1771 62.891 0.1772 62.891 0.1771 62.891"/><path d="m576.15 578.33h-63.075-63.075l-63.075-1e-4h-63.075"/><path d="m323.85 578.33 0.1772-62.891 0.1772-62.891 0.1772-62.891 0.1771-62.891"/><path d="m575.44 326.77 29.765-32.469 29.765-32.469" stroke="#c00000"/><path d="m634.97 261.83h-92.486-92.486l-92.486-1e-4h-92.486" stroke="#c00000"/><path d="m265.03 261.83 44.647 48.704 14.882 16.235" stroke="#c00000"/><path d="m323.85 578.33-15.092 13.725-30.183 27.45-15.092 13.725" stroke="#c0c000"/><path d="m263.48 633.23h93.258 93.258l93.258 1e-4h93.258" stroke="#c0c000"/><path d="m636.52 633.23-60.366-54.9" stroke="#c0c000"/><path d="m634.97 261.83 0.3863 92.851 0.3862 92.851 0.3863 92.851 0.3863 92.851" stroke="#0000c0"/><path d="m636.52 633.23h-93.258l-93.258-1e-4h-93.258-93.258" stroke="#0000c0"/><path d="m263.48 633.23 0.3863-92.851 0.3863-92.851 0.3863-92.851 0.3862-92.851" stroke="#0000c0"/></g></svg>'

def svg_to_stroke3(svg_string):
    # parse the doc
    doc = ET.fromstring(svg_string)
    # get paths
    paths = doc.findall('.//{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}path')

    strokes = []
    # previous x, y
    px, py = 0, 0

    for path_index, path in enumerate(paths):
        stroke = parse_path(path.attrib['d'])
        was_moving = False
        for operation_index, operation in enumerate(stroke):
            if isinstance(operation, Move):
                mx  = int(operation.start.real)
                my  = int(operation.start.imag)
                # prep this end point for check as next line first point
                was_moving = True

                strokes.append([mx-px, my-py, 1])
                # update previous (absolute) coordinates
                px = mx
                py = my

            if isinstance(operation, Line):
                sx  = int(operation.start.real)
                sy  = int(operation.start.imag)
                ex  = int(operation.end.real)
                ey  = int(operation.end.imag)
                if was_moving:
                    # append delta x, y relative to previous move operation
                    strokes.append([sx-px, sy-py, 0])
                    was_moving = False
                # append delta x,y (line end relative to line start)
                strokes.append([ex-sx, ey-sy, 0])
                # update previous (absolute) coordinates
                px = ex
                py = ey

                # update previous end point
    
    strokes_np = np.array(strokes, dtype=np.int16)
    return strokes_np

print(svg_to_stroke3(cubeSVG))
```

Additionally I've made the above available as an easy to run [Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BabeEnEcUDYQOwgihGGlKzBNpFz7ixp0?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conversion is correct, the bug is in the rendering code. It must be `is_down = data[i][2] == 0` instead of `is_down = data[i-1][2] == 0` in `draw_stroke3`.

[image]

This error didn't show up with the other paths as in all but two cases the new path starts at the end of the previous path. In the other case where you really move to a new start point the additional line coincided with a line already drawn.

---

**UPDATE AND CORRECTION:**
I noticed that I mis-interpreted the meaning of the pen-up bit: in fact it shows that the pen is to be lifted *after* drawing the current stroke, not *for* the current stroke as I though at first. Therefore your rendering code appears to be OK and the bug is in the stroke3 file generation.
I guess you can do it much simpler by recording the end points for each operation along with the op code (`1` = move, `0` = draw) for the current operation. After conversion to a numpy array we can easily convert these absolute positions the relative displacements by do the difference of the first two columns and then shift the third column with the op codes backwards by one position:

```
def svg_to_stroke3(svg_string):
    doc = ET.fromstring(svg_string)
    paths = doc.findall('.//{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}path')
    strokes = [[0,0,0]]
    for path in paths:
        stroke = parse_path(path.attrib['d'])
        for op in stroke:
            if isinstance(op, Move):
                strokes.append([op.start.real, op.start.imag, 1])
            if isinstance(op, Line):
                strokes.append([op.end.real, op.end.imag, 0])
    strokes_np = np.array(strokes, dtype=np.int16)
    # convert x,y columns to relative displacements
    strokes_np[1:,:2] -= strokes_np[:-1,:2]
    # shift back op codes
    strokes_np[:-1,2] = strokes_np[1:,2]
    # remove [0,0,0]s and set previous op to 0
    m = (strokes_np == 0).all(1)
    strokes_np[np.argwhere(m)-1,2] = 0
    return strokes_np[~m]
```

This gives a rather compact representation (49 rows for the example cube) and renders correctly with your original code and David Ha's `draw_strokes()` (you can do without the initial row I added if you by convention start with the pen up as `draw_strokes()` does).

Comment: Thank you Stef (+1). I am still a little bit puzzled though. I've rendered the same data using [David Ha's `draw_strokes()`](https://github.com/hardmaru/quickdraw-ndjson-to-npz/blob/master/util.py#L36) method and I still got that diagonal line which is why I'm confused. I've added this test [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jUKJZCM1wFZs_mil2Ib3TeEN3xVsua0s?usp=sharing). Notice the difference between `cube_gp` (my version of SVG parsing), `cube_dh` (SVG to lines, then [`lines_to_strokes()`](https://github.com/hardmaru/quickdraw-ndjson-to-npz/blob/master/util.py#L198))...

Comment: ...and `cube_dh_mod` which a version of `cube_dh` I manually edited to remove redundant `[0,0,0]` entries (modifying the previous stroke_3 bit from 1 to 0 to keep the pen down). This method has the least number of total strokes/seems the cleanest in terms of data. I do another cleanup pass programmatically, but how would you suggest generating the clean version in one clean pass rather than two ? (Sorry if this is a bit much, I can perhaps ask this as a separate question if that helps ?)

Comment: PS: if the matplotlib output is too small in your workbook you can do `plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))` before `plt.imshow(dbg)`

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much for the breakdown and taking your time to test and provide such an elegant solution. (Will need to wait 24 hours until I can award you extra points for the extra effort.)

Comment: Glad to be of help. I wish all questions on SO were so extremely well written as this one.